# Is there a regular expression dll or library that I can use for a language that does not have one?

Tags: regex, dll, dataflex

I program in Visual DataFlex.  Are there any libraries that I can use to give my programs regular expression matching?  It could be ActiveX, or COM, or maybe even just a DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that in some languages you can invoke something like CreateObject in VB. I think it is a COM object. So something like :

```
Dim re

Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

[Doc for VBScript Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

Answer (score 1):

MaxiWheat's answer is probably what you want, but you could also do what the pros do, and use the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) library.